# Is there a way to make the buttons bigger in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Wondering if there is a way to make the buttons in the toolbars BIGGER in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2008;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2wb0asd(v=VS.100).aspx

To display large icons on toolbars

From the Tools menu, choose Customize.

In the Customize dialog box, select the Toolbars tab.

Select the Use large icons option.

Comment: Ugh, it looks like this was removed in vs2010. The above link is wrong. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/eaf0e7eb-cb8d-4e1a-8d17-a7a56a0daf6f/